# Regarding @future annotation

Tags: apex

Can I upload data to Account Object in batches using @future annotation?

Or Only through BUlk Api we can upload in batches?

Please confirm me as I am new to this concept

Comment: Upload from where? Future methods can only be called by Apex Code, so that imples the data is already in salesforce...

Comment: i am not sure from where data is uploading because its done by one of my teammate. but she s uploading account object but only few are flowing to SAP.

Comment: If suppose using bulk api for data upload where can I moniter the logs? If suppose bulk api is used where is the code for creation of job and adding job to batches are present? please help me out

Comment: it would be great if you can update this question with your business process. which will help everybody to understand the requirements and we can then propose the solution